# Recursive search values by key

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON like this:

```
{ 
  "A": { "error": null },
  "B": { "C": {"error": "error string"}},
  "C": { "D": {"error": null}},
  "D": { "error": "err str"}
}
```

end I want to find all values of **error** keys which are not **null**.

For my example it should return

```
"error string"
"err str"
```

How can I do it? Is it possible with **jq**?

Comment: where is your code attempt?

Comment: I tried things like `jq 'select(.error!=null)' file.json` but it doesn't search recursively.

Comment: Have you tried searching, `jq search recursively` ?

Comment: Is it possible with jq? How to recursively search in bash?

Comment: @123 Sure. This here is the top hit.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `..` to iterate recursively, and get all the `.error` values. If they're `null`, remove them:

```
jq '.. | .error? // empty'
```

Alternatively, instead of using `empty` you can select the elements that are strings with `strings`:

```
jq '.. | .error? | strings'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that uses **tostream** and **select**

```
  tostream
| select(length==2 and .[0][-1]=="error" and .[1]!=null) as [$p,$v]
| $v
```

Comment: I wasn't previously aware of the `tostream`/`fromstream` functionality. That dramatically simplifies working with arbitrarily nested documents. Thanks!