# Get key names from JSON file recursively using jq

Tags: json, recursion, key, jq

I can get top-level JSON keys with `jq` as

```
jq 'keys'
```

E.g., see this question: [Get key names from JSON file using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118341/get-key-names-from-json-file-using-jq)

And I can enable recursion in `jq`:

```
jq '..'
```

As in: [Recursive search values by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459429/recursive-search-values-by-key)

But `jq '.. | keys'` returns `jq: error at <stdin> string has no keys`.

Answer (score 14):

Just ignore keys when they are absent for some values in JSON:

```
jq '.. | keys?'
```

Comment: this doesn't cleanly work with arrays of objects: 
$ echo  '{ "array1" : [ { "obj" : "data"} ] }' | jq '.. | keys?'
produces:
[
  "array1"
]
[
  0
]
[
  "obj"
]

Answer (score 1):

Ignore non-objects when inspecting for key names:

```
jq -r '.. | if type == "object" then to_entries[] | .key else empty end' "${LOCALAPPDATA}/Google/Chrome/User Data/default/Bookmarks" | sort --uniq
bookmark_bar
checksum
children
date_added
date_modified
guid
id
name
other
roots
synced
type
url
version
```