# Getting all nested values from a particular key in a given JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get all the date values in a json array for the dates inside the england-and-wales value.The array that like this (except it has a lot more values) the json array is here : https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

```
{"england-and-wales":{"division":"england-and-wales","events":[{"title":"New Year’s Day","date":"2015-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true}},{"title":"Good Friday","date":"2015-04-03","notes":"","bunting":false}]},"scotland":{"division":"scotla
nd","events":[{"title":"New Year’s Day","date":"2015-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true},{"title":"2nd January","date":"2015-01-02","notes":"","bunting":true},{"title":"Good Friday","date":"2
015-04-03","notes":"","bunting":false},{"title":"Early May bank holiday","date":"2015-05-04","notes":"","bunting":true}
```

As commented below the following will pick out all dates:

```
curl -s https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json | jq '.. | .date? // empty'
```

Im not sure how to only pick dates inside the england-and-wales array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive search values by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459429/recursive-search-values-by-key)

Comment: `curl -s https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json | jq '.. | .date? // empty'` should do the trick ^^

Comment: It does do the trick indeed thanks! Would you be able to explain it to me briefly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a stream of the dates for just "england-and-wales" efficiently:

```
.["england-and-wales"] | .events[] | .date
```

If you wanted these sorted and "uniquified", simply delay the itemization (`[]`):

```
.["england-and-wales"] | .events | map(.date) | unique[]
```

Comment: Looks like this works although the last outout is jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)
do you know why that is?

Comment: @jabra - I ran the jq script against the entire bank-holidays.json file without incident.