# jq Recursive search values by key, starting with

Tags: json, jq

**TL;DR**

What is [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s equivalent to `grep '"\/v6'` in the following command;

```
jq '.. .pattern? // empty' /tmp/all.json | grep '"\/v6'
```

---

Consider the following json;

```
{
  "payload": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "pattern": "/v6/",
        "groups": [
          {
            "pattern": "something/",
            "groups": [
              {
                "pattern": "somethingElse/",
                "groups": [
                  {
                    "pattern": "{specialPattern:[0-9]+}/",
                    "groups": [],
                    "routes": [
                      {
                        "type": "variable",
                        "pattern": "/v6/notImportant/{specialPattern:[0-9]+}/",
                        "methods": {
```

<sup>The json file is quite large, with a lot of irrelevant data</sup>

I'm trying to capture all the `.pattern` in the json file, [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459429/recursive-search-values-by-key) I've created the following jq command:

```
jq '.. .pattern? // empty' /tmp/all.json
```

This works as expected, creating a output similar to this;

```
"/v6/"
"something/"
"somethingElse/"
"{specialPattern:[0-9]+}/"
"/v6/notImportant/{specialPattern:[0-9]+}/"
```

---

**Question:** How would I *only* select each `.pattern` that starts with `/v6/` ?
I've used [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) like so

```
jq '.. .pattern? // empty' /tmp/all.json | grep '"\/v6'
```

However, there must be a `jq`-only solution to this.

---

Google taught me about jq's [`contains`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example49) that seems to be the answer on some-sort-of related question;

- [How to filter an array of objects based on values in an inner array with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538/how-to-filter-an-array-of-objects-based-on-values-in-an-inner-array-with-jq)
- [filter on "string contains"](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/33)
- [Print array element if it contains](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/861)

Unfortunately I can't manage to make it work with my situation, since using `select` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the selection, you could use

```
select( test( "^/v6/" ) )
```

So the command becomes;

```sh
jq '.. .pattern? // empty | select(test("^/v6/"))' /tmp/all.json
```

Or similarly with `startswith`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please provide a full example of the command?

Comment: @0stone0: pete means it to use it along with your original pattern - `.. .pattern? // empty | select( test( "^/v6/" ) )`

Comment: Any idea if using `select` is the only option? Only Using `test` isn't an option?

Comment: `def grep($s): select(test($s));`